# Filter Playa List by Custom Field

Tags: playa

I was able to successfully show a custom field in the Playa list by adding this snippet to the `views/entry.php`:

```
<?=$this->db->select('field_id_XX')->where('entry_id', $entry->entry_id)->get('channel_data')->row('field_id_XX')?>
```

All works well to show and list the custom field, but the filter breaks? Anyone know where I can update the filter to show the correct items when filtering?

**UPDATE:**

Did a little bit of digging after Alex mentioned the `droppanes.js` and `filter_entries()` method and it seems the filtering is done with AJAX as it queries the DB with the playa helper class: `system/expressionengine/third_party/playa/helper.php`.

Comment: If it is the JS that is breaking I'm guessing it will be in `/themes/third_party/playa/scripts/droppanes.js`. Can you elaborate a bit on _how_ it breaks (JS erros, behavior, etc)?

Comment: The filter finds the correct entries if you type a title. If you try searching the custom field I've added, nothing shows/wrong entries.

I added the custom field (model #) to the playa list to help differentiate the products (title). So when search for a model #, nothing shows

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the query that is used to build the filtered list isn't going to consider a custom field. The place to start is the `filter_entries()` method in `system/expressionengine/third_party/playa/mcp.playa.php`. This gets called every time you type to filter.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I just took a quick look and I think all the querying is done with `system/expressionengine/third_party/playa/helper.php`. ...Still beyond my expertise. Maybe someone with `PHP` chops can chime in.

Comment: Can you post the code for the system/expressionengine/third_party/playa/helper.php to http://www.pastie.org so we have reference and add a link back here? Will help.

Comment: Are you sure it is OK to post Pixel & Tonic's code from a commercial add-on publicly?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but then I thought it was only one file. I removed & deleted to be safe. I figured if someone wanted to help, they could check it with their copy of Playa.

Comment: Do you want to filter *just* on this custom field, or on the CF + title? Also, do you need to be able to target the CF per playa instance, or are you happy to have the filtering CF be global to your Playa install?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to use both the CF & Title. This is global so I'm not worried about defining per playa instance.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If yes, can you post your answer?

Comment: Nope, never got it working :(

Comment: I asked this feature to Brandon some time ago, but it seemed to be more complicated than what I thought in the first place. I digged the code myself, but it looks like it's a big hard hack of Playa.

Comment: Whats your full code in the views/entry.php? By the looks of it, i literally did the same thing last week, with the same code and the filter still works... Incidentally have you perhaps replaced the title rather than supplemented it, as i kept the title in, and put the custom field in afterwards, could image the filter requiring it.... just a thought

Comment: I have both the title & custom field for context. If I try a search for a value in the custom field, the results are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, modifying these files is not ideal and without some kind of conditionals you won't be able to reuse playa field types for anything else, but if you must here is what I did.

The 3 files that I needed to modify:

1. system/expressionengine/third_party/playa/ft.playa.php
2. system/expressionengine/third_party/playa/helper.php
3. system/expressionengine/third_party/playa/views/entry.php

First, in `ft.playa.php` in the `display_field` method you need to change the query:

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query(
                'SELECT * FROM exp_channel_titles
                WHERE entry_id '.$this->helper->param2sql($vars['selected_entry_ids']));
```

to join on the `exp_channel_data` table and select your custom field. This is for your saved selected item(s).

Next, in `helper.php` in the `entries_query` method you need to change the query being built in a few places to join on the `exp_channel_data` table and select your field. This is for the available unselected options. Also, in the same method under

```
if (isset($params['keywords']) && $params['keywords'])
```

you have to add a search for your custom field. This code is executed when a user is typing in the multi-select playa field via ajax to filter out entries. The filter for the single select playa field is just a javascript regex so, in that case, you need not worry about this.

Finally, you need to print your custom field in the `entry.php` file.

Comment: Thanks Rick! Now I just have to remember what site I was trying to do this for ;)