# How can Playa combine multiple category filters in the CP?

Tags: ee2, categories, playa, filter

I have a site with many similarly-named article entries that are organized by multiple categories. When selecting these articles in a Playa field in the control panel, I'd like to be able to select more than one category filter to narrow down the results.

Right now, adding multiple category filters displays entries that are in either one category or the other (e.g., it shows entries that are in either cat_1 OR cat_2). I want it to select entries that are in cat_1 AND cat_2.  Is this possible?

Using Playa 4.3.3 on EE 2.3.1. Thanks!

EDIT: This doesn't seem to be built in to Playa, but if anyone knows how to hack it so this works, I'd accept that as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this natively with Playa filters - you'd have to hack-in and change how it builds the query there (which would not be upgrade-safe).

Comment: Thanks, Derek. I'd be willing to hack Playa, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: This question may help you get started: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/filter-playa-list-by-custom-field