# Distinguishing duplicate channel titles in a PlayA field when adding a record

Tags: playa

For a field I am using PlayA and for the Field Options have selected two Channels.

The problem I have is that some of the titles within the two channels are the same and therefore when adding a new EE record it is impossible to tell from which of the two channels a particular title is from. Is there a solution to this?

I am guessing that as I am ordering by Entry Title, the first entry will be from the first channel and the second entry will be from the second, but I do not know if I can be certain of this.

The obvious solution of changing the titles in one of the channels is not an option for this particular web site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hack in this thread may point you in a direction: [Filter Playa List by Custom Field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/filter-playa-list-by-custom-field)

Looks like it may not play well with the ajax filtering however.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. Until Playa adds an inline "filter by channel" option within the playa fieldtype (something I would LOVE to see down the line), mirroring "filter by category", the latter is in fact an easy workaround.  When I face this same challenge, I'll often create a category group that has a category per channel, and assign that category group to each of the channels in question. Then when creating an entry in each channel, I also assign the entry to the category that matches the channel - purely for filtering via the Playa field. Not ideal by any means, but in a pinch, it works, but makes two assumptions: (a) that the channels in question are not already clogged with category group assignments and (b) that the admin will remember to assign the categories in the entry screen (there are add-ons to make the category assignment a little more noticeable than they would otherwise be on the category tab, making them harder to overlook).

As long as with your Playa field you don't limit the selections to those categories, the filters work great (meaning, if a category assignment is forgotten, the entry still shows in the list when a category filter is NOT applied, just in case).