# Differentiate Playa entries

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

Is there a way in the control panel to differentiate between channel entries that have the same title? We have a 'related course' field that looks at courses and have several 'science' courses that are further defined by category but there's no way to see this.

We need to be able to choose any course but also see its category.

Comment: You should be able to filter by category - but if two with the same title are in the same category, not much help.

Comment: Yeah, knew I can obviously filter by category in the field setup. I think we may need to differentiate the titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack Playa to show custom fields, etc.–the downside is that it displays that information for every Playa field. See more here: [Filter Playa List by Custom Field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/filter-playa-list-by-custom-field)